# Trying to update Jira Cloud issue's custom field of type wiki-renderer

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

I have created a textArea custom field and set the renderer type to wiki-renderer.

I have associated this custom field to one of my projects and am trying to use Jira Cloud REST API to edit the value on said field

Using Groovy at the moment in ScriptRunner Script Console

```
def customFieldValue = "h1. Hello World"
def body = [
  "fields": [
    "customfield_10040": [
      "rendererType": "atlassian-wiki-renderer",
      "value": customFieldValue
    ]
  ]
]

def resp = put("/rest/api/3/issue/PJ-3")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(body)
        
        .asObject(Map)


return resp
```

The response I get back is "INVALID_INPUT" and I can't figure out what is the right way of doing this. This is just for testing the API's functionality so the example is for a simple paragraph.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Setting a text field's render type as `wiki-renderer` only changes the way that field's content is represented (rendered) to the user *via the GUI*, it has absolutely no effect on how the content of that field must be provided *via the REST API*.

With Jira Cloud's v3 REST API, you must provide the content of all text fields using [Atlassian Document Format](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/apis/document/structure/) (ADF).

If you want to provide the content of that field using the old wiki markdown format, you have to use the old Jira Cloud v2 REST API endpoints.